# How to access data index in CoreData using Swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, swift3

I saved datas in entity of `CoreData.` Also I can access data in CoreData through `object.value(forKey:"attribute")`. But, I don't know how to access data using index.

follow code is my access way

```
    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Entity> = Entity.fetchRequest()
    let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest){
       for object in result
       object.value(forKey:"attribute")...
       ...
       }
    }
```

How to access data in `CoreData` using index of data?

Comment: Your `result` is array and each object in array is `dictionary` so basically which index you are talking about?

Comment: Actually, I wanted a way that to get index from object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is type of `Array` so you can access the object from result like `result[0]` and so on.

```
if index < result.count {
    let obj = result[index]
}
```

If you want index from object, you can use `index(of:)` for that.

```
if let index = result.index(of: obj) {
    print(index)
}
```

Comment: When I achieved data, using this data, I hope get a index of data